# Installing a condition handler in Common Lisp

Tags: exception, lisp, common-lisp, conditional-statements

The HTTP library Drakma on CLISP generates an error USOCKET:UNSUPPORTED due to a bug in Drakma+CLISP. However, it turns out that the CONTINUE restart seems to work fine. Therefore, I spent some time with CLtL and other references trying to determine how to write a restart handler.

```
(defun http-request (url param)
  (handler-bind ((USOCKET:UNSUPPORTED
          #'(lambda (x)
              (invoke-restart 'continue)))))

  (drakma:http-request url
               :method :post
               :parameters
               param))
```

According to my best understanding, the above code should trap the error USOCKET:UNSUPPORTED. It doesn't; it seems to ignore the error binder.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I am not sure if I can help you here, but: Your parens are totally messed up. Try it like this:

```
(defun http-request (url param)
  (handler-bind ((usocket:unsupported #'continue))
    (drakma:http-request url :method :post :parameters param)))
```

If that doesn't work, try checking whether you are really handling the correct condition, and whether the restarts you expect really are available:

```
(defun http-request (url param)
  (handler-bind ((condition (lambda (c)
                              (print c)
                              (print (compute-restarts)))))
    (drakma:http-request url :method :post :parameters param)))
```

Alternatively, you could take a look at [`IGNORE-ERRORS`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_ignore.htm)

Comment: I was pulling from a tutorial page - I didn't realize that the form sequence under test was in the `handler-bind` form.